# C++ compiler ID vendor not found by cmake in plane c++ Qt creator Project on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, ubuntu-14.04, qt-creator

I want to use Qt creator with cmake build system on Ubuntu 14.04 for plain c++ development. When I compile the simple hellow world code, I get this error:

/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:446: error: execute_process given COMMAND argument with no value. /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:48 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR) /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:127 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID) CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

Although, my cmake works fine, if I compile code using cmake on command line. I do not know how to set the that vairable or even should I ?

Comment: Seems cmake cannot understand the vendor_id of your compiler, I think that Qt is telling cmake to use a compiler and something is wrong with that compiler. Have a look here.  http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html

Comment: @Marco thanks for comment. The issue was, Qtcreator does not supper cmake less than 3.x.x version and by default 14.04 has 2.8.2 cmake version. I update the version and now it works fine.